# Override the :root in html and css in django template

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project and during it I had to use `:root` to set the font size. However I also need to override it in the next section and I can't seem to do it.

I used the root from the online template [here](https://codepen.io/GeorgePark/pen/VXrwOP).

However in the `main` section I failed to reset the `html` font size to `16px`. This is my code:

**layout.html:**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link href="{% static 'cs50gram/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">

        {% block style %}{% endblock %}

        {% block script %}{% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="nav-background">
            <a class="navbar-brand" id="nav-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">CS50gram</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home </a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'explore' %}">Explore</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' request.user %}">Profile</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'add-post' %}">Add Post</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="body">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap 4 CDN -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The main page where I want to reset the `font-size` in `<main>`:

```
{% extends 'cs50gram/layout.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    Profile
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    
    <header>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="profile">

                <div class="profile-image">

                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1313117763519606784/IkM0WYGt_400x400.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" width="150px">

                </div>

                <div class="profile-user-settings">

                    <h1 class="profile-user-name">{{ profile.user.username }}</h1>

                    {% if user.is_authenticated and request.user.username == profile.user.username %}
                        <button class="btn profile-edit-btn">Edit Profile</button>
                    {% elif user.is_authenticated and request.user.username != profile.user %}
                        <button class="btn profile-edit-btn">Follow</button>
                    {% endif %}

                    <!-- button class="btn profile-settings-btn" aria-label="profile settings"><i class="fas fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></button -->

                </div>

                <div class="profile-stats">

                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="profile-stat-count">{{ profile.user.posts.count }}</span> posts</li>
                        <li><span class="profile-stat-count">188</span> followers</li>
                        <li><span class="profile-stat-count">{{ profile.followings.count }}</span> following</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="profile-bio">
                    <hr>

                    <h2 class="profile-real-name">{{ profile.user.first_name }} {{ profile.user.last_name }}</h2>

                    <hr>

                    <p> <b> Date Joined:</b> {{ profile.user.date_joined|date:"D d M Y" }}

                    {% if profile.birthdate %}
                        <span style="margin-left: 10px"> <b> BirthDate: </b> {{ profile.birthdate }}</span></p>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if profile.gender %}
                        <p> <b> Gender: </b> {{ profile.gender }}</p>
                    {% endif %}

                    <hr>

                    {% if profile.bio %}
                        <p> {{ profile.bio }}</p>
                    {% endif %}

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End of profile section -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of container -->

    </header>

    <main>     <!-- Here I want to restore font-size to 16px -->
        <div class="container">
            {% for post in profile.user.posts.all %}
                <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #f4f6f6">

                    <!-- Username -->
                    <a href="{% url 'profile' post.posted_by %}"><h5 class="mt-2"> @{{ post.posted_by }} </h5></a>


                    <!-- Post image -->
                    <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-fluid" width="550px">

                    <!-- Like Icon and Counter -->
                    <img data-id="{{post.id}}" id="post-like-{{post.id}}" class="liked"
                        {% if request.user in post.like.all %}
                            data-is_liked="yes"
                            src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/32/fa314a/hearts.png"
                        {% else %}
                            data-is_liked="no"
                            src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/like--v2.png"
                        {% endif %}
                    /> <span id="like-counter-{{post.id}}"> {{ post.like.count }} </span>

                    <!-- Comment icon and counter -->
                    <span class="comment-pointer" data-id="{{post.id}}" id="view-comments" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/speech-bubble--v1.png" class="comment-icon"  /> <span id="comment-counter-{{post.id}}"> {{ post.comments.all.count }} </span>
                    </span>

                    <!-- Caption -->
                    {% if post.caption %}
                        <h5 class="mt-2"><strong>{{ post.posted_by }}</strong> {{ post.caption }}</h5>
                    {% endif %}

                    <!-- Date Posted -->
                    <h6 class="gray">Posted on {{ post.date_posted }}</h6>

                    <!-- Add Comment -->
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment" id="post-comment-{{post.id}}" class="form-control mr-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark comment" data-id="{{post.id}}" type="button">Add Comment</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Show comments -->
                    {% if post.comments.all %}

                        <!-- Gets the comments of each post based on the related_name -->
                        {% for comment in post.comments.all.reverse|slice:":2" %}
                            <div>
                                <a href="{% url 'profile' comment.commented_by %}"><b> {{ comment.commented_by }} </b></a>
                                <span class="gray"> {{ comment.comment }} </span>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}

                        <!-- Div to show recently added comment -->
                        <div id="recent_comment"></div>

                        <div class="text-center mb-2 view-all">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{post.id}}" id="view-comments" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">View all comments...</a>
                        </div>

                    {% endif %}

                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </main>

{% endblock %}

{% block style %}
    <link href="{% static 'cs50gram/profile.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
```

Please note that the `profile.css` is taken from the link provided above.